# How to get access to Azure Resource Management REST API?

Tags: azure

I've been trying to get access to the REST APIs exposed by Azure such as "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2016-06-01" but no matter how hard I try I always get an "Unauthorized" response. I aquire a brearer token for the call like this:

```
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.windows.net/{0}", azureADTenantId), false);
ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(azureADAppClientId, azureADAppClientSecret);
AuthenticationResult authResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com", clientCred).Result;
return authResult;
```

This makes use of the ADAL NuGet packages from MS. I do get a token which I pass like this:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(authResult.AccessTokenType, authResult.AccessToken);
```

After which I use said HttpClient to make the call to the above URL which is followed by a 401 response. What's wrong? FYI I followed the following guide to setup the Application I'm using to make the connection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal

Comment: Please try by pretending "Bearer " in front of your access token. There should be a space between the word "Bearer" and the access token.

Comment: @GauravMantri the header is built with new AuthenticationHeaderValue class, it is correct.

Comment: Aah....I didn't know that. Thanks for letting me know. One more thing you can try is appending a "/" to "https://management.azure.com". If that doesn't help, then you read the response text of your web exception and you should see more details about the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have located the issue: Apparently the "Readers" role in Azure is bugged and does not grant access. The least required level of access is "Contributors" to be able to read from the REST Services.